# How to format Exception's stack trace in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

When Exception is displayed (or more general - when it is converted to String) stack trace is shown. What I want to do is to change the format of source code's file paths shown in such trace.

Specifically I would like to leave filenames only (without full path) or show only that part of path which starts with project's base directory. Full paths are usually unnecessary and clutter the whole message.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I asked a similar question, although not entirely the same, here: [Print stack trace information in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768/print-stack-trace-information-from-c).

What you can do is this:

```
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(exception);
```

which gives you a [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) object that gives you all the information you need. In my case it was about avoiding having to deal with localized exception text, but I'd imagine you can use the same approach for your needs.

---

**Edit**: I note that I have added a comment to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768/print-stack-trace-information-from-c/51803#51803) to my question related to a "needFileInfo" parameter to the constructor. I see this constructor here: [StackTrace(Exception e, bool fNeedFileInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt.aspx), I can't find the actual code in question right now but I would guess you need to pass `true` to that argument. I guess experimentation is the key here.

In other words, I guess the code should be this:

```
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(exception, true);
```

Comment: How is this different from `exception.StackTrace`?

Comment: Exception.StackTrace is a String, this is a class that gives programmatic access to the parts of the stack trace, including file names, line numbers, class names, etc. in pieces, not as a single string.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the System.Diagnostics.StackFrame class and the [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilename.aspx) method.  You can write a method that will get the stack trace and the names of the source files that you can call in your exception handler.