# Conversion failed during calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my **stored procedure**:

```
[dbo].[DFW_Completed_Safety] (
    @StartDate VARCHAR(10),
    @Station VARCHAR(50),
    @EmployeeID INT)
```

When I **code** the following:

```
SqlDataAdapter daAC_CSM = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dsAC_CSM = new DataSet();
try
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;               
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "DFW_Completed_Safety";
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startdate);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", station);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", "0");
        daAC_CSM.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
        daAC_CSM.Fill(dsAC_CSM);
    }
    return dsAC_CSM;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

it throws the Exception: ***EmployeeID*** is received as a varchar.

> `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'd ' to data type int.`

**Things I tried:**

1- Many others post on StackOverflow suggested that `Convert.ToInt32(0);` would do it. Since 0 is an Int32 by default, this isn't a solution. 
2- Changing the method to receive varchar (send "0") and it doesn't work too.

Thanks for any ideas! (would be greater to keep the method signature to Int).

**UPDATE:** The question isn't answered yet, since changing my stored procedure to varchar didn't make it.. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to convert your date to varchar, or change your stored proc to expect datetime data type?

Comment: Greg look at my update I forgot the MAIN point of the question (EmployeeID is received as a varchar.)

Comment: Sorry. Missread it before my Monday morning coffee. Have you tried calling the stored proc from SSMS to see if you get the same error?

Comment: Have you tried using [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters(v=vs.80).aspx) to derive the parameters instead of setting them yourself?

Comment: Greg: Don't be sorry it's my mistake. Yes I tried it, using 0 as EmployeeID just like in C# (Execute Stored Procedure) and it works on SSMS. I don't know why it does there and not in C#..

Comment: Luxspes: What's that? I'm sorry it's the first time I see that.

Comment: @user1106649 please look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Please rewrite your code like this:

```
try
{
    sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter daAC_CSM = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet dsAC_CSM = new DataSet();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "DFW_Completed_Safety";
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startdate);  //Using "@"
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", station);    //Using "@"
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", 0); //Using "@"

    foreach(SqlParameter p in  sqlCmd.Parameters){
      //Will print Name, Type and Value
      System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Name:" + p.ParameterName + "Type: " + p.DbType+" Value: "+p.Value); 
    }

    sqlCon.Open();
    daAC_CSM.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
    daAC_CSM.Fill(dsAC_CSM);
    sqlCon.Close();
    return dsAC_CSM;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

What does it print? What error do you get?

Comment: Name:StartDateType: String    ;
Name:StationType: String      ;
Name:EmployeeIDType: Int32

Comment: Ok, did you try with  `command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int);command.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value = 0;`

Comment: Also, why are you not using the "@" in your parameter names?

Comment: And, what does it print if you call the foreach WITHOUT using DeriveParameters?

Comment: Because @ in SQL Server is a variable.

Comment: Tell me more about foreach without using DeriveParameters?

Comment: If you look at the example in the MSDN documentation of [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) it uses the "@" in the parameter name

Comment: Name:@StartDateType: String  ;
Name:@StationType: String  ;
Name:@EmployeeIDType: Int32  ; Same deal.

Comment: Ok, now try using  `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", 0);`  with @, instead of `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", 0);`

Comment: That's what I just did (e.g. Name:@StartDateType: String ; Name:@StationType: String ; Name:@EmployeeIDType: Int32 ; Same deal.)

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a ' to data type int. (instead of 'd ', it's 'a ')... Thanks

Comment: That is what I currently have

Comment: Well, then tell what it is priting now (it should print Name, Type and Value for each parameter)

Comment: Name:@StartDateType: StringValue: 07-18-2012SqlValue: 07-18-2012 ;
Name:@StationType: StringValue: XY SqlValue: XY ;
Name:@EmployeeIDType: Int32Value: 0SqlValue: 0

Comment: Can you please add the full exception message and stacktrace to your question? I am suspecting your problem is not in the parameter, but in the code inside your stored proc

Comment: [SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a ' to data type int.]

Comment: That is not the full exception message and stacktrace, (and it is not added to the question)

Comment: Here is how a stacktrace looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768/print-stack-trace-information-from-c-sharp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14256/discussion-between-user1106649-and-luxspes)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your procedure from SSMS you will most likely get the same error, as the error is most likely derived from the body of your procedure, rather than how you are calling it. If you have a value 'd ' in a column in the table that you're querying from - and you are comparing that column to an integer type, then you will receive that error. Also, a couple of asides:

- You should be putting your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` instances in a using clause or disposing of them manually since they are IDisposable.
- You probably don't want `throw ex` in your catch block - you probably just want `throw`. By using `throw ex` you mess up the stack trace that was available in the original exception.

Comment: I did what you said, look above to look what I changed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it wasn't the first line. The FormName is a field that stores the FormID. The programmer that was here before was probably a noob or changed the Column datatype to int, making all queries not to work. Thanks anyways @Matt_Whitfield & @Luxspes. By the way Luxpes, you were right, it was written line 1 even on SSMS, but I did it using the same:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[DFW_Completed_Safety]
        @StartDate = N'07-18-2012',
        @Station = N'YHZ',
        @EmployeeID = 0
```

And by doing Print @SqlStatement, I was able to copy & paste in a new Query and see that it was the Form**Name** that was an Int. Who knew that a Name could be an Int?